# if statement not responding (python)

Tags: python

the if statement is not responding. I'm trying to get the `gcd(20,6)`
the program outputs: `gcd(20,6): 20=6(4) + -3`, I need it to be if the last number(-3) is less than 0 the the program should output `20=6(3) + 3`,but the if statement isn't responding.

```
rnumtup = (20, 6)
if rnumtup[0] > rnumtup[1]:
    x= rnumtup[1]
    y =rnumtup[0]
w = x / y
w = round(w)
z = x - (y*w)
z = round(z)

while z != 0:
    x = y
    y = z
    w = x / y
    w = round(w)
    z = x - (y*w)
    z = round(z)
    if z > 0: #not responding
        #some statements
    if z < 0: #not responding
        #some statements
```

Comment: And what `if z==0`?

Comment: z can be  equal to 0 , nothing less that that

Comment: this is python 3.5

Comment: i just don't understand why the if statement is not responding

Comment: Because as Gábor points out, z is *always* 0 by the time it gets there.

Comment: In Python 3.x, try to use `//` for getting quotient, i.e., `20//6=3`

Answer (score 0):

`z` is equal to `0`, so your `if` statements aren't doing anything.

Explanation in the code comments

```
rnumtup = (20, 6)
if rnumtup[0] > rnumtup[1]:
    x= rnumtup[1] #x = 20
    y =rnumtup[0] #y = 6
w = x / y #w = 3
w = round(w) # Does nothing
z = x - (y*w) # z = 2
z = round(z) # Does nothing

while z != 0:
    x = y # x = 6
    y = z # y = 2
    w = x / y # w = 3
    w = round(w) # Does nothing
    z = x - (y*w) # z = 0 --> If statements don't work, while loop ends after first iteration
    z = round(z)
    if z > 0: #not responding, because z == 0
        #some statements
    if z < 0: #not responding, because z == 0
        #some statements
```

Note that in python `20/6` equals `3`, but `20.0/6` equals `3.33333..`

Comment: w= round() is for numbers that will produce a number with a decimal point ,e.g x = 888, y =54, then w =16.4

Comment: Yes, that is why it does nothing. 20/6 is 3, NOT 3.33 as you would expect.

Comment: @Gábor Erdős as the OP said Python 3.5, `20/6` is 3.33. `20//6` is 3

Answer (score 0):

You would think that z cannot be 0 because of

```
while z!=0:
```

but when your program reaches the statement

```
z= round(z)
```

z can be 0 and you program checks only for strictly positive or negative numbers since 0>0 is false, a better gdc function would be [euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), here is the python 3 version

```
def gdc(a,b):
   while a!=b:
      if a>b:
         a=a-b
      else:
         b=b-a
   return a
print(gdc(20,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an alternative, thanks guys :)

```
rnumtup = (20, 6)
if rnumtup[0] > rnumtup[1]:
    x= rnumtup[1] 
    y =rnumtup[0] 
w = x / y 
w = round(w) # Does nothing
z = x - (y*w) 
z = round(z) 

if z< 0:
    w = x / y
    w = round(w)
    w = w-1
    z = x - (y*w)
    z = round(z)

while z != 0:
    x = y # x = 6
    y = z # y = 2
    w = x / y # w = 3
    w = round(w) # Does nothing
    z = x - (y*w)
    if z< 0:
        w = x / y
        w = round(w)
        w = w-1
        z = x - (y*w) 
    z = round(z)
```